# custom interactive map using html/jquery

Tags: jquery, dictionary

We do have a game program and every game has some regions say R1, R2, R3 etc. and every region has some users like U1, U2 etc. and every user has some factories and warehouses to create/store their products. Now we would like to display these info in graphical view like google map. So we want display regions like map then display user factories and warehouses like google markers. Please let me know if there are any plugin available in jquery or javascript.

Comment: Have you looked at the official Google maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps/ Here is a simple map marker implementation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: thanks, I already saw that. These are real location based on latitude and longitude. But we don't store latitude and longitude for the regions. Just store their name. Google map could be a trick to show my regions if we hide the real location and add my regions as custom location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use already maps on html.

Check: [HTML 'map' Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)

but you have to specify regions for each image/component after defining all regions use image events with jQuery via their **#id**'s.